# How to remove a selection of table rows from a table using detach()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, html-table, slice, detach

I have a table, which I want to split into rows of x, which should be removed from the table and added to subpages I'm creating. I can slice the table, but `detach()` doesn't work and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is what I have:

```
    var rows = $( table ).find( "tbody tr, TBODY TR" ).toArray(),
        splitRows = [];

    for( i = 0; i < rows.length; i += rowsPerPageS ){

       // table rows for each subpage
       var takeAway = splitRows.push( rows.slice(i, i + rowsPerPageS ) );

       // split the tabel and create subpages
       newPage = takeAway.detach()
                         .wrap(...
       }
```

**Question:**
Console tells me *takeAway.detach is not a function* and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. How do I remove my sliced table-rows and wrap them correctly?

Comment: From what I can tell, `takeAway` will be a standard array, not a jQuery object, so you can't use jQuery functions with it.

Comment: so if it make it a Jquery object like above...? - nah. doesn't work

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - but I think this is going in the right direction. If you want to make answer, I will check.

Comment: If `takeAway` **is** an array of DOM elements, as I suspect, then `$(takeAway)` should give you a jQuery object containing those DOM elements. You should then be able to call `.detach()` on it. Would be more helpful if you could produce a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with whatever you have currently.

Comment: found the solution. posted above. thx for help!

Comment: @frequent You should post your solution below and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution. This works:

```
var rows = $( table ).find( "tbody tr, TBODY TR" )
    splitRows = [];

for( i = 0; i < rows.length; i += rowsPerPageS ){

    // split table into array
    splitRows.push( rows.slice(i, i + rowsPerPageS ) );

    // table rows for each subpage
    var takeAway = splitRows[i],
        newPage;

    // split the table and create subpages
    newPage = takeAway.detach()
                      .wrap...
```

So I guess I need to split into the array first and then takeaway the respective array elements.

Thanks for helping!